# chrome not offering to save openid password

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, password-management, openid

when I go to forums, chrome will ask if it wants to remember the password I say yes. and if I log out of the forum it fills it in for me and I just click log in.

this doesn't seem to be the case with this superuser site.

Answer (score 0):

The only times this happened to me, I found that I was not logged on to my OPENID site, and in that case, the OPENID would not be completed. Since then, when I want to log in using OPENID, I first log on to my OPENID provider. I have had no problems since.
Regards,

Comment: I am not trying to use a cookie which keeps me logged in. I may use that too but that's not relevant.  The idea with chrome remembering the password, is that after logging out, chrome can fill in the details so I can log in easily. Like it does with any other forum.